# how to query public IP in ELK on python?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

```
public IP ：

class A： 1.0.0.0~9.255.255.255 11.0.0.0~126.255.255.255

class B： 128.0.0.0~172.15.255.255 172.32.0.0~191.255.255.255

class C： 192.0.0.0~192.168.255.255 192.169.0.0~223.255.255.255

private IP：

class A： 10.0.0.0～10.255.255.255

class B： 172.16.0.0～172.31.255.255

class C： 192.168.0.0～192.168.255.255
```

If I want to query pulic IP in ELK on python ,how can I do?

I exclude private IP with wildcrd but not work.

```
          {
            'query':{
                'bool':{
                    'must_not':{
                        'wildcard':{
                            'field':'10.*.*.*  192.168.*.* 172.16.*.*  172.17.*.* ... 172.31.*.* 
  192.168.*.* '
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: you should add indices mapping to question.

Comment: because of wildcard query is very resource killer, I suggest to add a field to your indices that indicate public and private IP.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [`elasticsearch-py`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py) library.

A Little example:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from datetime import datetime
es = Elasticsearch(
    ['localhost', 'otherhost'],
    http_auth=('user', 'secret'),
    scheme="https",
    port=443,
)

es.index(index="my-index", id=42, body={"any": "data", "timestamp": datetime.now()})
```